# Calc rotation around pivot point perpendicularly to camera (like TransformControls but always directed to the camera)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have been trying to calculate the transform rotation from the current camera view on mouse move. Similar to the "TransformControls" component in Three.js, but the control should always be directed towards the camera. From this perspective, the rotation I would like to be calculated and later applied as texture rotation.

Here are steps I've attempted:

1. Click on the mesh to find the 3D pivot point, which will be the center of the texture in the future
2. Set the position of the intersect plane at the 3D pivot point (for raycasting purposes) and make it oriented the camera using `lookAt(camera)`.
3. Drag mouse around and the plane to calc the rotation around the pivot point

Here's a screenshot illustrating my setup:
[image: Here's a screenshot illustrating my setup:]

However, I'm facing an issue where the rotation only works properly when the camera is oriented looking down at a specific angle. When the camera looks up, the rotation seems to be inverted, and at other angles, the behavior is inconsistent, as if it's not aligning with its projection axis.

I've also created a CodeSandbox example to demonstrate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/rotation-438sgd?file=/src/App.js

**Note: The crucial part for me is calculating the 2D angle perpendicularly to the plane's view from the camera perspective.**

Thank you in advance for your help!